# Почему "ботать по фене", но "говорить по-русски", "говорить по-японски"?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему во фразе "ботать по фене" не ставится дефис, но ставится во фразе "говорить по-русски"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Потому что "по-русски" - это наречие, исторически его принято писать через дефис, а в выражении "ботать по фене" слово ["феня"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F) - это существительное, именно эта форма прижилась, вот если бы мы говорили, например, ботать по-офенски, тогда бы ставился дефис.

Иными словами, дефис не ставится по той же причине, по которой мы не ставим дефис в "разговаривать по правилам".

Comment: Почему "по-офенски", а не "по-фенски"? Откуда лишняя о? Мы же не говорим "по-офински" :)

Comment: @SergeySlepov потому что офени )

Comment: Я так понимаю, в этой самой фене ещё и предлоги употребляются не так, как в нормативном русском (ср., напр., «рассказать за что-то» вместо нормативного «про что»/«о чём»). Поэтому переводом выражения «ботать по фене» на литературный русский должно быть «говорить на фене». Впрочем, я могу и ошибаться.

Comment: `говорить по-латыни` тоже пишется через дефис, хотя тут существительное  `латынь` :)

Comment: @user7808407 говорить по-латыни - это разговорная версия говорить "по-латински", как "чё" и разговорная версия "чего" - в случае же фени такого наречия от которого можно образовывать разговорную версию не было.

Comment: @user7808407 `говорить НА латыни`

Comment: @Sugar почему бы не погуглить перед тем как писать?

Answer (score 4):

В правилах русского языка явно присутствуют правила написания дефисов в наречиях

```
Через дефис пишутся наречия: 
1. с приставкой кое- и суффиксами -то, -либо, -нибудь : 
      кое-где, где-то, куда-либо, откуда-нибудь;   

2. имеющие приставку по- и оканчивающиеся на   -ому (-ему), -ки, -ьи :   
      по-иному, по-моему, разделить по-братски, по-волчьи выть;   

3. образованные от порядковых числительных, имеющие приставку в- (во-) и суффикс -ых (-их) :   
      во-первых,   в-третьих;   

4. образованные повторением того же самого слова или той же основы: 
      дышать еле-еле, всего-навсего, мало-помалу, нежданно-негаданно, точь-в-точь.
```

*по-русски*, *по-английски*, *по-китайски*, *по-человечески* и прочие попадают под второе правило и собственно потому так и пишутся. Ботать по фене не попадает ни под одно из правил, кроме того является жаргоном, что в может в принципе делать его исключением из правил (но не в этом случае).

Answer (score -7):

Смотри, "ботать по фене" это вообще не "по-русски", это одесские евреи привнесли свой "суржик" в русскую речь.

Я точные координаты не скажу, но где то тут:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaNjPAFD-UI Русские евреи. Фильм первый. С предисловием Леонида Парфенова
Parfenon
1 year ago

Или во втором фильме, или в третьем, Парфёнов очень складно объясняет происхождение множества блатных слов. Как например, "Мусара" - с Иврита "Мосе`р" - в переводе "Осведомитель", т.е. стукач.

Comment: по-русски - это если есть де-факто использование в русском, различать истинно русское от неистинного - довольно неблагодарное занятие. Вас человек спросит про слово "хлеб", вы ж не начнёте ему объяснять, что это на самом деле германское слово.

Comment: А как тебя в школе учили? - Почему Кофе не склоняется? Почему Радио не склоняется? .. потому что это исконно русские слова?:??? эй ало ... минусинск... смотрите ютуб! учите мат часть!

Comment: подавляющее большинство заимствованных слов склоняются по правилам русского языка, но это в любом случае не имеет отношения ни к заданному вопросу ни к данному вами ответу

Comment: Какое подавляющее? Кофе, какао, пальто, метро, интерьвю, депо, бюро, жюри ... - да их миллион. А тех что окончательно обрусели - их больше, вот это да! Вы капитан очевидность! Я сообщаю "топик-стартёру", что "ботать по фене" - это точно так же как кофе - не русское слово/выражение. И не надо тут искать правила применимые к русским словам. Кофе - это арабское قهوة qahwa. "Ботать по фене" - это Иврит עִבְרִית. Вас не устраивает такая аналогия? Что то более конкретное - по теме будет, а это - уход в сторону? я правильно понял вашу направленность?

Comment: а я сообщаю вам, что слова конь, пуля, изъян, лошадь и кабан - это заимствования, если нужны заимствования из идиш, то пожалуйста - "по блату" например. сама по себе неисконная природа происхождения слова ещё ни о чём не говорит